# DIV height adaptable to browser

Tags: html, browser, height

I am re-building my website with DIVs, I want a DIV's height to adapt to the height of the browser, I can easily do that by positioning the DIV as absolute and then using "bottom-padding:0", however I need my DIV to be positioned as "relative" and therefore I can't get this result. This is my website (work in progress):

http://www.antoniofx.com/test/

As you notice, the RED box goes below the footer, I want the red box (a div) to stop where the footer is (even if I resize the browser) so that the content inside the red box will end when the browser end and then scroll if there is more content, instead of just pass the footer and going below it. I have researched this but couldn't find any solution. Thanks!